# Why atime is not preserved in tar?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, tar

According to the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar), `tar` is capable of preserving the access time, but when I tried the same, it failed to do so. Can someone please explain this?

```
$$$:~/user1/testtar/source> tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1
```

Create two files with older timestamp

```
$$$:~/user1/testtar/source> touch -t "201501010101" a.txt
$$$:~/user1/testtar/source> touch -t "201501010101" b.txt

$$$:~/user1/testtar/source> ls -ltu
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr usr 0 2015-01-01 01:01 a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr usr 0 2015-01-01 01:01 b.txt
```

Move it to another folder

```
$$$:~/user1/testtar/source> tar --atime-preserve -cvpf archive.tar *
$$$:~/user1/testtar/source> mv archive.tar ../target/
$$$:~/user1/testtar/source> cd ../target/
```

Extract the tar

```
$$$:~/user1/testtar/target> tar --atime-preserve -xvpf archive.tar
a.txt
b.txt

$$$:~/user1/testtar/target> ls -lt
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr usr 10240 2016-07-07 15:55 archive.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr usr     0 2015-01-01 01:01 a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr usr     0 2015-01-01 01:01 b.txt
```

Result

```
$$$:~/user1/testtar/target> ls -ltu
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr usr 10240 2016-07-07 15:56 archive.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr usr     0 2016-07-07 15:56 a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr usr     0 2016-07-07 15:56 b.txt
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The referenced man page is confusing.  Where it says of `--atime-preserve`

> preserve access times on **dumped** files [...]

(emphasis added), [the current docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_70.html) say

> Preserve the access times of files that are **read**."

(emphsis added).  The word "dumped" refers to putting a file into a tar archive, not to extracting a file to the file system.  Thus, the `--atime-preserve` option is for archiving files without causing the originals' atimes to reflect the access.  This is useful in support of making incremental backups (dumps).

Under no circumstances does `tar` fail to set the atimes of files that it extracts, contrary to your expectation.  It certainly cannot give them the same atimes as the originals, for the tar file format does not even record atimes.

Answer (score 3):

You can observe in the [tar format specification](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html) that there is no atime field. This is just to preserve access time of the original file being tar-ed.

Comment: Why would you say the atime is not present in the tar format specification? atime (together with mtime and ctime) are all specified in the header as well as documented. I just simply use vi to open the tar (binary) file and see mtime, atime, and ctime are stored in plain text. Unfortunately I not yet able to simply restore the atime unless manually `touch` the extracted files afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think this topic is obsolete, with exactly the same steps, I got the following result.

```
tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.28

mkdir -p source target
touch -t "201501010101" source/a.txt
touch -t "201501010101" source/b.txt
tar -cvpf archive.tar -C source  .
tar -xvpf archive.tar -C target/

ls -l target/
total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usr usr 0 Jan  1  2015 a.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usr usr 0 Jan  1  2015 b.txt
```

Comment: `ls -l` lists only the mtime (modify time) but not the atime (access time).